# How to get a visual reference to the div represented in console variable

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, firefox, browser

This question concerns Firefox and Chrome.  Though if you would like to include other browsers in the answer too, that would be great (though I definitely want Chrome and FF!).  When debugging my HTML & Javascript application, I frequently end up with variable in my console that references a div on the page.  However, I am frequently at a loss for figuring out how to determine which div it actually references.  Is there some to get a visual reference for that?  For example, I have a variable called `myDiv`.  I know it's a div on the page, though I don't know which one.  Perhaps there's a special browser command like `myDiv.hilight()` which will visually highlight that div on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you type `myDiv` in console, and it returns an element that is part of the HTML structure, then when you hover over the returned element (in Chrome console), it will highlight that element on the page.

It's a little hard to explain, but if variable is myDiv, try typing `myDiv` and pressing enter in the Chrome developer console. When it outputs an  element, hover your cursor over it.

Same result you can achieve by using `console.log(myDiv)` in your script if the variable is not global and thus cannot be accessed from Chrome console directly.

Comment: Cool, so that works for Chrome.  And for Firefox I installed Firebug which has the same feature.